# UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity Permissions

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I'm attempting to use the .NET `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` library to obtain the UserPrincipal for a particular Active Directory user.

I've got the following code:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DomainName");
userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
```

This code is running as a valid domain user, but when I execute it I get the following exception:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007052E): Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

What's interesting is that I can make the following call, using the same context, without a problem:

```
context.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate)
```

Ideas?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863801/findbyidentity-failing-with-pricipaloperationexception-in-asp-net-webapp/3515280#3515280

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the the `PrincipalContext` constructor that takes username and password.

The reason that Validate works is because its using the provided credentials to bind to the directory.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. You're saying that the ValidateCredentials call uses the current identities credentials, but the UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity call, which accepts the context in question, doesn't? If that's the case, how do I get it to use the current identity (as in, the thread's identity) to make the call? I don't have a username or password to pass, as this is an application running as a service account setup at install time. I can't store these credentials anywhere.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, ValidateCredentials uses the credentials provided in the parameter list for ValidateCredentials -- the Context you've defined has no credentials associated with it besides the ones of the current thread. I suspect your issues is in the configuration/deployment of the server. Make sure the account running the service has been delegated to within the domain.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood. The current thread's user is definitly a valid domain user. When you say "delegated to within the domain", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: In the Active Directory Users and Computers (on the domain controller) you need to select the Organizational Unit you want to manage, and "Delegate Control" in the delegate wizard, put in the credentials that your service is running as.

Comment: So I'll need to do that even if I never use the context to make any changes? I'm only using the FindByIdentity call to obtain detail information about the user. Also, I've got this code working in one environment in which I created a new domain account and did nothing special whatesoever. I never told it to delegate control, nor did I put the user in any group except domain users. The only diff between the two domain is the working one is Win2k8 and the broken one is Win2k3. Did this change between those versions?

Comment: As far as I know, that *shouldn't* be any different between Windows 2008 and Windows 2003 domains. If you're only reading data, you delegation may not be necessary.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test your ideas, but you were the most helpful, so I'm awarding you the bounty. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a stored network credentials.  In Windows, you can specify to use a different network credentials when trying to reach a network resources.  I can reproduce exactly the same problem as you are seeing by setting up a wrong network credentials.

Assuming your domain is called `yourdomain.com`, you can tell Windows to always use a specific username and password whenever it talks to any computers with suffice yourdomain.com.

=== Windows 7/2008 ===

1. Launch the "Crendentail Manager".
2. Under Windows credentials section, click `Add a Windows credentials`
3. In network address, put in `*.yourdomain.com`
4. In username and password, put in a wrong username or wrong password

=== Windows XP/2000/2003 ===

1. Click Start and Run
2. Type in `control keymgr.dll`
3. Click Add button on "Stored User Names and Passwords" dialog
4. In server text box, put in `*.yourdomain.com`
5. In username and password, put in wrong username or wrong password

If this is really the problem that you are facing, the easy fix is to remove the stored passwords.

Why does context.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate) work?  It's simply because you are initializing another Kerberos/NTLM authentication since you provides `uername` and `password` again.  Under the hood, if Kerberos is chosen, it would send the domain controller the provided username and password and exchange for a Kerberos TGT ticket.  Then, your machine get a service ticket on the LDAP server using this TGT ticket.  Then, your machine will send this service ticket to the LDAP server.  Note that this service ticket won't be retained in the current logon session.

Why `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity` doesn't work?
If you don't have any stored password, normally it should work because Windows will just use the current logon user TGT ticket to exchange for the LDAP server service ticket.  There is no username/password validation process involved.  However, if you do have a bad username password, Windows would think it shouldn't use the current logon user TGT ticket.  Instead, it should get a new TGT ticket using the stored network password.  That's the reason you are seeing `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007052E): Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.`

Comment: Interesting. This code is running from withing the context of an ASP.NET application, so I wouldn't think stored passwords would make a difference. I'll check to see if you're correct.

Comment: @RMD Ah, you missed this piece of information.  Are you using Windows Authentication?  Or are you simply using the local service account to access the AD?

Comment: As I said in my original post: "This code is running as a valid domain user".

Comment: @RMD If you are using ASP.NET, there are two accounts involved.  One is the service account you used to run ASP.NET.  Another one is the user account who logon to the ASP.NET web page.  So, we need to know whether you configured ASP.NET to use Windows Authentication or not.  We also need to know whether you are using a domain account as the ASP.NET service account.

Comment: The application is not setup to impersonate, and the application pool in question is running as a valid domain user. I've verified this. The real problem, as Nate outlined above, appears to be that .NET is ignoring the contextual credentials when making the FindByIdentity call.